# What is the equivalent function of PHP's number_format in C#?

Tags: c#, php, number-formatting

Say I have these values:

```
var upSize = 365308443361.28;
var downSize = 351897407979.52;

var size = upSize/downSize;
```

In PHP I can do this:

```
number_format(size, 3);
```

and the output would be: **1.038**

How can I do the same in C# with string.Format()?

Comment: That output would require the second parameter to be 3, not 2.

Comment: Right, that is correct. I just edited the question to the proper parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shorter (and less flexible) alternative to Darin's code:

```
size.ToString("0.000")
```

or

```
size.ToString("f3")
```

Comment: Also a pretty nice solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you could use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
var upSize = 365308443361.28;
var downSize = 351897407979.52;
var size = upSize / downSize;
string result = string.Format("{0:0.000}", size);
```